# How to use iterview function from python couchdb

Tags: python, python-3.x, couchdb

I have been working with couchdb module in python to meet some projects needs. I was happily using view method from couchdb to retrieve result sets from my database until recently.

```
for row in db.view(mapping_function):
    print row.key
```

However lately I have been needing to work with databases a lot bigger in size than before (~ 15-20 Gb). This is when I ran into an unfortunate issue.

db.view() method loads all rows in memory before you can do anything with it. This is not an issue with small databases but a big problem with large databases.

That is when I came across [iterview](http://pythonhosted.org/CouchDB/client.html#couchdb.client.Database.iterview) function. This looks promising but I couldn't find a example usage of it. Can someone share or point me to example usage of iteview function in python-couchdb

Thanks - A

Comment: What happens if you simply call `iterview` the way you called `view`?

Comment: It still comes back with all the rows. I even tried passing a value for 'batch' to limit the return size, as they say in the document. That dint worked either

Answer (score 0):

Doing this is almost working for me:

```
import couchdb.client
server = couchdb.client.Server()
db = server['db_name']
for row in db.iterview('my_view', 10, group=True):
    print row.key + ': ' + row.value
```

I say it almost works because it does return all of the data and all the rows are printed. However, at the end of the batch, it throws a KeyError exception inside couchdb/client.py (line 884) in iterview

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. You need to add `include_docs=True` to the `iterview` call, and then you will get a `doc` attribute on each row which can be passed to the database `delete` method:

```
import couchdb
server = couchdb.Server("http://127.0.0.1:5984")
db = server['your_view']
for row in db.iterview('your_view/your_view', 10, include_docs=True):
    # print(type(row))
    # print(type(row.doc))
    # print(dir(row))
    # print(row.id)
    # print(row.keys())
    db.delete(row.doc)
```